# Move Data from Oracle Server to Azure Blob Storage with Incremental Changes or delta load

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I have a problem with the incremental load I want to create an delta load (incremental load) pipeline from the Oracle on-premise server to Azure data lake(blob storage) I don't have Azure SQL. I just want to push in blob storage as a CSV file. in my case, I am confused about how can I do this?. someone told me in your case you have to use parquet delta. please help me with this I am stuck for many days.

First I loaded with full load (copy activity) now I want load only new data from oracle server with triger every week on sunday.

PLease help in this issue!
Thanks in advance
Waris

I need help in pipeline to build increment load only new rows from oracle server to azure data lake

Comment: Refer this [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview#delta-data-loading-from-database-by-using-a-watermark) for incrementally copying data.

Answer (score 0):

In the copy activity, instead of selecting the table option in the source, you can select Query and there you can write your select statement with where clause on any timestamp column (ex: `loadtimestamp >= getdate()-7`) for incremental data load.

[copy activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAWMG.png)

Comment: Thanks Jithin, with Query I got the new data rows but now I would like to know How I can  merge/append These new rows in my Previous master CSV file

Comment: I think there is no direct approach to merge/append the new rows to the existing CSV file. It's always better to keep the files separated.

Comment: If you still want to have the data in a single file, you can add one more copy activity, and in source you can point to the folder containing CSV files and in the sink you can write it to one CSV file.